# Irregular behavior of c++ code

Tags: c++

I wrote C++ code, that seems to have nothing wrong. I use Code::Blocks as an IDE, and it didn't give me any warnings nor any errors, but when I run it, it gives me the box that says that my exe file is not responding.

My code is the following:

Header File:

```
// DVD_App.h - Header File

#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

enum Status {ACTIVE, INACTIVE};

class Customer {
    private:
        string id;
        string name;
        string address;
        Status status;

    public:
        Customer (const string&, const string&, const Status);
        string &getId () { return id; }
};

class CustomerDB {
    private:
        static map<string, int> idList;

    public:
        static void addNewToIdList (const string &threeLetterOfName) {
            idList.insert(pair<string, int>(threeLetterOfName, 0));
        }

        static bool doesThreeLettersOfNameExist (const string &threeLetterOfName) {
            map<string, int>::iterator i = idList.find(threeLetterOfName);
            if ((i->first).compare(threeLetterOfName) != 0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        static int nextNumber (const string &threeLetterOfName) {
            map<string, int>::iterator i = idList.find(threeLetterOfName);
            ++(i->second);
            return i->second;
        }
};
```

Source Code:

```
// DVD_App.cpp - C++ Source Code

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DVD_App.h"

using namespace std;

map<string, int> CustomerDB::idList;

Customer::Customer (const string &cName, const string &cAddress, const Status cStatus) : name(cName), address(cAddress), status(cStatus) {
    string threeLetters = name.substr(0, 3);
    if (CustomerDB::doesThreeLettersOfNameExist(threeLetters))
        threeLetters += "" + CustomerDB::nextNumber(threeLetters);
    else {
        CustomerDB::addNewToIdList(threeLetters);
        threeLetters += "0";
    }
}

int main () {
    Customer k ("khaled", "beirut", ACTIVE);
    cout << k.getId() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to first check that my CustomerDB class is working, but I can't since the program isn't running. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lol. `I wrote a C++ code, that didn't have anything wrong`

Comment: What heppens if you err.. debug it? Does it get into main() at all?

Comment: @Component10: LOL a typo

Comment: @Martin: How can I debug it, I'm new in C++ so I dont know how exactly to do so

Comment: @alzen92 use gdb/cgdb on linux(also on windows with cygwin) or visual studio debugger on windows. There are also other options but these are the ones I typically use.

Comment: @aizen92 Don't start by using all those magic classes without knowing how they work. You'll only learn that C++ is confusing and "behaving irregularly".

Comment: If you cannot debug, you cannot program.  Learning to write some code that compiles is 10% of the job.

Answer (score 2):

Your `idList` is initially empty, so when you call `doesThreeLettersOfNameExist` the iterator `i` you get returned by `find()` will be the `end()` iterator which you may not dereference.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in the function doesThreeLettersOfNameExist if `i == idList.end()`. If that happens you cannot check `if ((i->first).compare(threeLetterOfName) != 0)`. And by the way that happens on the first iteration. Also add this to nextNumber.